# I am facing "TypeInitializationException" while executing selenium(C#) Script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am new to Selenium and am trying to understand different areas of it. I have come across a situation where I have 3 classes under namespace Automate_Dynamics365.

1. Class **POM** contains all the elements in a page which are declared as public static IWebElement txtusr = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xxxxxx”));
2. Class **Demo** is where I have the actual test cases (I am using NUnit framework’s attributes like SetUp, Teardown, Test)
3. Class **Methods_Factory** contains several methods which use **POM** class webelements.

The below logic is not working as I am getting an error during runtime.[This is just an example]

```
Class POM
{
public static IWebElement txtusr = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xxxxxx”));
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Class Methods_Factory
{
Public static void Login()
{

POM.txtusr.sendkeys(“YYYYY”);
}
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Class Demo
{
[Test]
Public void ex()
{
Methods_Factory.Login();
}
}
```

Error:  [Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Z9n.png)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**The below logic is working**

```
Class Methods_Factory
{
Public static void Login()
{
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xxxxxx”)).sendkeys(“YYYYY”);
}
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Class Demo
{
[Test]
Public void ex()
{
Methods_Factory.Login();
}
}
```

Please help me understand how do deal with this situation.

All I am trying to do is to maintain all the page elements in one class, methods in another class which would use the Iwebelements from the previous class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which class you are creating drive instance ?

Comment: In which class you are creating drive instance ?

Comment: I have created a property for driver in POM class.

    public static IWebDriver driver {set; get;}

I have instantiated driver in Demo class as

POM.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();